# Error on assets:precompile due to Model in engine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

My situation is a follows:

- I'm running application X
- X uses the gem "core"
- core extends the models of X with models A, B, C, D

In development this works perfectly. However when I run

```
(bundle exec) rake RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile
```

it fails on

```
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant A
```

I tried to fix this issue by placing Rails.application.eager_load! before the `Application.initialize!` in environments.rb, but I'm afraid that only led to other errors.

Is there a way to include models from an engine in a gem BEFORE the assets:precompile?
I read something about requiring them one by one instead of eager_load all, but the path to the gem differs for every system.

engine.rb in "core":

```
require 'paperclip'

module Core
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    config.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/**)

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, :views => false, :fixture => true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
    end

    initializer "core.load_app_instance_data" do |app|
      Core.setup do |config|
        config.app_root = app.root
      end
      app.class.configure do 
        #Pull in all the migrations from Commons to the application
        config.paths['db/migrate'] += Core::Engine.paths['db/migrate'].existent
      end
    end

    initializer "core.load_static_assets" do |app|
      app.middleware.use ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public"
    end    
  end
end
```

I prefer to put any fix in the core gem instead of application X. However if it's not possible X is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the "core" gem is loaded in the staging environment?

Comment: Indeed, the gem was only loaded in development, test and production. Often the solution is way simpler then you expect.